# Install powernap on debian?

Tags: software-installation, tar, power-management

I just read about powernap [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2045541) but don't know how to install it..

Download and untar was simple:

```
axel https://launchpad.net/powernap/trunk/2.20/+download/powernap_2.20.orig.tar.gz && tar -xvf powernap_2.20.orig.tar.gz
```

**Content of powernap_2.20.orig.tar.gz:**

```
/powernap-2.20
|-- /actions
|    `-- ..
|-- /bin
|    `-- ..
|-- /man
|    `-- ..
|-- /powernap
|    `-- ..
|-- /powerwake
|    `-- ..
|-- /sbin
|    `-- ..
|-- action
|-- ChangeLog
|-- config
|-- config_migrate.py
|-- DESIGN
|-- powernap.spec
|-- powernap-ethtool
|-- powerwake_completion
|-- powerwake.conf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well @stevepusser from forums.debian.net helped me :)

The trick is to create a package from the ppa. The official tutorial with much more details can be found here: [debian/wiki/CreatePackageFromPPA](https://wiki.debian.org/CreatePackageFromPPA)

### But to install powernap you should follow these steps:

- Install the Debian SDK: `apt-get install devscripts build-essential`

- Add the PPA source url to your sources.list:

1. Find the `deb-src` by "Adding this PPA to your system" > "Technical details about this PPA"
   For powernap it's https://launchpad.net/~powernap/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
2. Add the source to your source lists:
   `echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/powernap/ppa/ubuntu utopic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/powernap.list`
3. Add the keys to your system:
   `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <signing key>`
4. **IMPORTANT!!** Update your sources:
   `apt-get update`
5. Create a folder for the *.deb files:
   `cd ~ && mkdir powernap && cd powernap`
6. Build your files:
   `apt-get source --build powernap`